# Remove reboot request for DISM

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

I want to automate the upgrade of my 2012 R2 servers from standard to datacenter.

However, there is a prompt at the end of the upgrade waiting for a user response. I have thousands of servers to do and cannot press "Y" at the end of it... any ideas how I can get the prompt to accept "Y" or "N" ?

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what's the reason you want to "upgrade" to datacenter? Are these physical servers? The only difference between standard and datacenter is the amount of virtual guests you're allowed to run...

Comment: Try `echo Y |  DISM /online…`.

Comment: Dude, hide your product key...

Comment: @JonathanKortleven that's the normal KMS setup key.  Nothing private there.

Comment: OP - have you tried the /quiet option?  I'm pretty sure that suppresses the need to tell it to restart.

Comment: @TheCleaner - yeah, /quiet and norestart worked perfectly

Comment: @MichelZ - its all to do with politics in my company...told them it is exactly the same but they want to save Microsoft costs so they want default as standard...so if anyone wants to upgrade (which most will!) then this is their option for now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
/Quiet
```

Your servers will reboot automatically if no error occured.

OR

```
/NoRestart
```

You won't be prompted to reboot.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj980032%28v=winembedded.81%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: thanks a lot for that - the /NoRestart worked. I took a look at the help on the command line but did not look at the documentation. Thanks - that's worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Or force the reboot.. at the end if you 'press' Y it equals to reboot command.. so try creating this kind of script:

```
shutdown -f -r -t 1
```